# Physical interpretation of $L_1$ and $L_2$ norms

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, mathematical-physics, signal-processing

In signal analysis, students have no qualms about associating the $L_2$ norm of a square integrable function $f(t)$ as the **energy** associated with that signal.

A good understanding of whether a function $f(t)$ is a square integrable function is to picture whether it has finite amount of energy. I find this to be an extremely useful knowledge.

However, when I plot the $L_1$ norm of a given function, all I'm getting is the total positive area lying under the curve. Which leads to two important questions:

1. How did $L_2$ norm get associated with being the energy of a signal? I.e. what is the physics involved?
2. What is the physical interpretation of the $L_1$ norm? I find "area" not very convincing not only given the enormous physical intuition behind the $L_2$ norm but an area is still more of a construction from a mathematical perspective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I can't satisfyingly answer your question about the $L_1$ norm, the $L_2$ norm has an easy answer.

Remember that a signal is generally, physically speaking, some sort of electronic oscillation in voltage (or current, if you prefer to think of it that way).
It is well known that [instantaneous power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power) of an electronic signal is given by
$$
\frac{dE}{dt} = R[I(t)]^2 = \frac{1}{R} [V(t)]^2
$$
Where $I$ refers to the current, $V$ refers to voltage, and the resistance $R$ is some time-independent coefficient.  It follows then that the total energy expended, assuming a signal of finite energy is transmitted between times $\pm \infty$, is given by
$$
E_{total} = \frac 1R \int_{-\infty}^\infty |V(t)|^2\,dt
$$
The utility of the $L_2$ norm as being representative of "energy" does extend beyond this particular context.  However, at the very least, it does make physical sense here.

Overall, the $L_2$ norm will always have a bit more mathematical utility than the $L_1$ norm since the $2$-norm is derived from an inner product, whereas the $L_1$ norm is not.

A useful property of the $L_1$ norm in the context of signal analysis is that an LTI-system is [BIBO-stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability) iff its transfer function has a finite $L_1$ norm.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation of Omnomnomnom of the $L_2$ norm is very good alreay.

One possible interpretation of the $L_1$ norm, or rather the ration between $L_1$ and the $L_2$ norm is that it can be used as a measure of sparsity or compressability of a signal. Therefore it has often been used as a regularization term in optimization problems. Today this is a research field on its own called [*compressed sensing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing). You might want to have a look at the linked Wiki page for reading up on the used techniques and the intuition behind the usage of the $L_1$ norm.

Comment: Isn't that the $\ell_1$ norm instead?